# Dynamic SQL (where) in Firebird stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, where-clause, firebird, firebird2.5

I Have an SP that receive 2 parameters, `P1` and `P2`, like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MY_PROC (P1 varchar(10), P2 smallint = 1)
RETURNS (
    code      VARCHAR(10),
    name      VARCHAR(70),
    state     VARCHAR(2),
    situation VARCHAR(20)
AS 
    ...
    ...
```

And I need to generate the `where` clause based on the `P2` parameter, like this:

```
if (P2=1) then
    where (state='SP' and situation='stopped')  
elseif (P2=2)
    where (state='MG' and situation='moving')
```

How to use this type of `if` statement in where clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me your question translates as a simple `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause of a SQL query:

```
WHERE
   (:P2 = 1 AND state='SP' and situation='stopped')
   OR (:P2 = 2 AND state='MG' and situation='moving')
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer of GMB will work fine for most situations, but in more complex cases it may have less desirable performance. An alternative solution would be to build a query string dynamically and execute it with [`execute statement`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt):

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MY_PROC (P1 varchar(10), P2 smallint = 1)
RETURNS (
    code      VARCHAR(10),
    name      VARCHAR(70),
    state     VARCHAR(2),
    situation VARCHAR(20)
AS 
declare query varchar(2048);
begin
  query = 'select ......';
  if (p2 = 1) then
    query = query || ' where (state=''SP'' and situation=''stopped'')';
  else if (p2 = 2) then
    query = query || ' where (state=''MG'' and situation=''moving'')';

  -- if you expect a single result
  execute statement query into code, name, state, situation;

  -- OR

  -- for multiple results
  for execute statement query into code, name, state, situation do
    suspend;
end
```